# How to call Entitlements api of SubscribeWithGoogle service for each user already registered

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

Hi i need to call this api of google to retrive informations about all users already registerd to my app with their google account.

in Google console i created a new service account to enable "server to server" calls.
this code gets the access token:

```
//json with the credentials to access
var pathJson = @"xxx.json";
var json = File.ReadAllText(pathJson);
var cr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonalServiceAccountCred>(json);
var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(cr.client_email)
        {
            Scopes = new[] { "https://subscribewithgoogle.googleapis.com/v1/publications/entitlements" /*Here put scope that you want use*/}
        }.FromPrivateKey(cr.private_key));

        var accessToken = credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync().Result;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("accessToken->" + accessToken);
```

the access token is geenrated correctly, but calling the api:

```
https://subscribewithgoogle.googleapis.com/v1/publications/PUBLICATION_ID/entitlements?access_token=GSI_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

with publicationid of my app and the access token generated above i get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, 
  login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See 
  https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
  "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
}
}
```

this code is inside a class library, i need a batch process to run daily i cannot do it into a web project.

Comment: Which api exactly are you accessing can i get a link to the doucmentaiton?

Comment: this one https://developers.google.com/news/subscribe/reference/publication-api

Comment: That results in a 404 do you have access a private api or something?

Comment: yes, you need permission to navigate

Comment: i added an email of a subscribed user and the error changed.TokenResponseException: Error:"invalid_scope", Description:"https://subscribewithgoogle.googleapis.com/v1/publications/entitlements is not a valid audience string.", Uri:""

Comment: Yeah as far as i can tell that's not a valid scope. I cant find any information on this api. NO idea where you are getting that scope from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be setting the access token as an authorization header.

```
GET https://subscribewithgoogle.googleapis.com/v1/publications/PUBLICATION_ID/entitlements  HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```